# How to fwrite from heap memory array INSIDE STRUCT?

Tags: c, file, pointers, heap-memory, fwrite

The problem with `fwrite()`ing from heap memory is you are literally just writing a pointer to data. Possibly to recover the same data when you execute the code again. But nothing guarantees that the pointer will be the same as the pointer to the old data. I need help `fwrite()`ing heap memory.

```
struct {
    char SomeStringData[12];
    struct LittleStruct* LittleStructArray;
} BigStruct = {
    .SomeStringData = "HELLO WORLD",
    .LittleStructArray = malloc(sizeof (struct LittleStruct)*NumberOfArrayElements);
}

fwrite(&BigStruct, sizeof(BigStruct), 1, DataFile);
```

Comment: A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the address to something else as its value. When you use the pointer itself as an argument to `fwrite`, `fwrite` does not simply write the pointer, it begins writing information at the address held by the pointer. (e.g. it starts writing from the memory address pointed to by the pointer)

Comment: First, what you just described is your obligation to prepare a [mcve]. So do that. Second, I can plainly see the issue this code is having, and your opening observation so-much-as-says so. You're writing the value of a *pointer* to your file using `fwrite`, not the data it actually *points to*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The worst thing is, that I didnot tell ye this before, but I have to succesfully save: A struct to a file, and one of the struct members is a malloced array.

Comment: Then you must *serialize the data*. You would write the struct out and immediately following the struct write an `unsigned` value holding the number of bytes that are allocated to the pointer in your struct, now write those bytes out. Reading back in, you read the struct, read the next `unsigned`, allocate that amount, and then read the bytes into the new block of memory and assign the starting address for the block to the pointer in your struct, repeat for the next struct....

Comment: `"HELLOWORLD"` is NO-LONGER a `string` in `SomeStringData[10];` (you don't have room for the `'\0'`, e.g. you are short by one-character). At minimum `SomeStringData[11];` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write using fwrite you are only interested in that the content of where the pointer points to is written to the disk. When you fread from the same file, you don't normally care where in memory the data is read in.

```
 char* p = malloc(10); // some arbitrary address on the heap
 strcpy(p, "hello");
 fwrite(p, 1, 6, somefilepointer); // now what p points to is written
```

when you now read with fread, the values are placed where q is.

```
 char* q = malloc(10); // some other arbitrary address on the heap
 fread(q, 1, 6, somefilepointer);
```

**EDIT** : after question got changed.

When you allocate again inside your struct, you will need to write that part separately since it will exist in another part of the heap. fwrite only writes consecutive bytes, so writing your struct would be something like

```
fwrite(&BigStruct, sizeof(BigStruct), 1, DataFile);
fwrite(BigStruct.LittleStructArray, 
  sizeof(BigStruct.LittleStructArray), NumberOfArrayElements, DataFile);
```

better

```
fwrite(BigStruct.SomeStringData, 1, sizeof(SomeStringData), DataFile);
fwrite(BigStruct.LittleStructArray, 
  sizeof(BigStruct.LittleStructArray), NumberOfArrayElements, DataFile);
```

Comment: You may also want to write an `unsigned short` or `unsigned` containing the number of chars to read before the string as without it, there isn't any way to know how many bytes need to be allocated or read.

Comment: hi i edited my question to reflect something further that this answer does not cover, but thx

Comment: @JulianTiemann you should not change the question when people have answered your question, it can make existing answers wrong. most people who answer a question do not return to the question, at least not directly, they may just do reply and then move on. it is better to do a new question.

Comment: @Anders sORRY but could someone please edit this answer to reflect my new edits

Comment: So then, thanks for telling me how to write. But how do I read the file... Actually nevermind I could figure it out

Comment: Just read in the same way, you may want to skip writing the whole BigStruct and just write the first part (SomeStringData) and then add LittleStruct since the actual pointer value is useless.